# Handle rowspan and colspan while converting "Table" into "Div"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am converting table structured data into div using below code.

```
$('#content').html($('#content').html()
             .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div id='table'")
             .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div style='overflow:auto;padding-top:15px;'")
             .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
             .replace(/<td/gi, "<span  style='float:left;margin-right:20px;'")
             .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
             .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div"));
```

It works good mostly in all scenario except ROWSPAN & COLSPAN case.

How can I handle that design issue while converting Table into Div ?
I am stuck in that.

Comment: I can't think of an easy automated method to do that. But why the hell are you want to display tabular data in a `DIV`-soup? Via JavaScript? [Using regex to parse HTML!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454)

Comment: @feeela : Its a requirement to fit data properly into content so.

Comment: Why are you converting a `table` to `div`s using JavaScript?

Comment: @thirtydot: any other method welcome if it gives a solution.

Comment: [A solution to what problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this gets you in the right direction:

```
.replace(/rowspan="/gi, 'class="rowspan-')
.replace(/colspan="/gi, 'class="colspan-')
```

Then make styles for the classes (e.g. rowspan-2 or colspan-3 etc.). However, this doesn't solve cases where one element has both row- and colspan, but it's a start.

A better way would be:

```
var copyAttr = function(old, $new) {
  for(var i = 0,
        attributes = old.attributes;
    i < attributes.length; i++) {

    $new.attr(attributes[i].name, attributes[i].value);
  }
  return $new;
}

$('#content').find('tbody').each(function() {
  var $new = copyAttr(this, $('<div id="table"></div>');
  $(this).replaceWith($new);
}).end().find('tr').each(function() {
  var $new = copyAttr(this, $('<div class="tr"></div>');
  $(this).replaceWith($new);
}).end().find('td').each(function() {
  var $new = copyAttr(this, $('<span class="td"></span>');
  $(this).replaceWith($new);
});
```

So now you have replaced the whole table structure with divs and spans with all the attributes the table elements had. Next you can change the row- and colspan attributes to classes.

```
$('#table .td').each(function() {
  var $t = $(this);
  $t
    .addClass('rowspan-'+$t.attr('rowspan'))
    .removeAttr('rowspan')
    .addClass('colspan-'+$t.attr('colspan'))
    .removeAttr('colspan');
});
```

Comment: The second is definitely the way to go.. Don't parse. Use selectors.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you converting table structured data into div instead of just outputting div structured data in the first place? I don't really get that

You can try using CSS:

```
.tablewrapper
{
  position: relative;
}
.table
{
  display: table;
}
.row
{
  display: table-row;
}
.cell
{
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
}
.cell.empty
{
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
}
.cell.rowspanned
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Some example table which you should get:

```
<div class="tablewrapper">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        Top left
      </div>
      <div class="rowspanned cell">
        Center
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Top right
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        Bottom left
      </div>
      <div class="empty cell"></div>
      <div class="cell">
        Bottom right
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In you case this will look like:

```
.replace(/rowspan="/gi, 'class="rowspanned cell')
```

This example works in all major browsers except for Internet Explorer 7.